# sqlalchemy filtering using text and like a json column

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

i am working on a query where i need to filter on a json field, it is working when i am comparing using equal operators

```
User.query.filter(text("COALESCE(user.country_info ->> 'name', '') = 'UK'")).all()
```

but when i use the ***like*** operators `search_value = '%{}%'.format(text_search)` where text search is a string like **'united'** it don't work

```
User.query.filter(text(f"COALESCE(user.country_info ->> 'name', '') like '{search_value}'")).all()
```

and i when print the query in text i see that i am getting something like

```
user.country_info ->> 'name' Like '%%united%%'
```

if i remove the **%** sign the query became

```
user.country_info ->> 'name' Like 'united'
```

any help here

Answer (score 0):

found the correct way, i had to use sqlalchmey expression bindparam

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import bindparam
from sqlalchemy.types import String

search_value = "%{}%".format(search_value)    
search_param = bindparam('search_text', search_value, String)
User.query.filter(text(f"COALESCE(user.country_info ->> 'name', '') like :search_text").bindparams(search_param)).all()
```